# .NET Core Dependency Tree

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to view dependencies for a project in a .NET core application?  I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

At the moment I have the following Nuget packages referenced in my `csproj`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="4.0.8" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Where you can navigate dependencies.

[image: dependencies]

But it makes it hard to find a particular dependency - a tree is good if you know what you are looking for.  Is there a way to output a flat list of dependant assemblies and there versions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add an msbuild target to your project file (inside the `<Project>` element) like this:

```
<Target Name="PrintAllReferences" DependsOnTargets="RunResolvePackageDependencies">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Referenced package: %(PackageDefinitions.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

Which you can call like this (a line without a parent package name means it is referenced by the project directly):

```
$ dotnet msbuild /nologo /t:PrintAllReferences
  Referenced package: Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/1.1.0
  Referenced package: Microsoft.NETCore.Targets/1.1.0
  Referenced package: Microsoft.Win32.Primitives/4.3.0
  Referenced package: NETStandard.Library/1.6.1
  Referenced package: runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.fedora.23-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.fedora.24-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.native.System/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.native.System.IO.Compression/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.native.System.Net.Http/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.Apple/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.opensuse.13.2-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: runtime.opensuse.42.1-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/4.3.0
  Referenced package: System.Buffers/4.3.0
  Referenced package: System.Collections/4.3.0
  …
```

If you wanted a "reverse dependency tree" - a list of packages and which packages reference them - you can do something similar to:

```
<Target Name="PrintPackagesAndParents" DependsOnTargets="RunResolvePackageDependencies">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="* %(PackageDependencies.Identity) referenced by:%0a^---@(PackageDependencies->'%(ParentPackage) - target %(ParentTarget)', '%0a^---')" />
</Target>
```

which produces the following output:

```
$ dotnet msbuild /nologo /t:PrintPackagesAndParents
  * JetBrains.Annotations/10.2.1 referenced by:
  ^--- - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  * System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives/4.0.1 referenced by:
  ^---NETStandard.Library/1.6.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/4.0.1 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.IO.FileSystem/4.0.1 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.Xml.ReaderWriter/4.0.11 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  * System.Linq/4.1.0 referenced by:
  ^---NETStandard.Library/1.6.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding/4.0.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  * System.Linq.Expressions/4.1.0 referenced by:
  ^---NETStandard.Library/1.6.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  * System.Net.Http/4.1.0 referenced by:
  ^---NETStandard.Library/1.6.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  * System.Net.Primitives/4.0.11 referenced by:
  ^---NETStandard.Library/1.6.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.Net.Http/4.1.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  ^---System.Net.Sockets/4.1.0 - target .NETStandard,Version=v1.3
  …
```

There isn't really documentation about these items, but they have "public" name and are generated by the [ResolvePackageDependencies](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/ResolvePackageDependencies.cs) task which is executed as part of the [RunResolvePackageDependencies](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/cd25d6bbfc2aac61cc790c511900427ac64fdaa8/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets#L170-L182) target and produces a few very useful items: `TargetDefinitions`, `PackageDefinitions`, `PackageDependencies`, `FileDependencies` and `DiagnosticMessages`.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Also, if you save the command in a batch file called `dotnet-printrefs.bat` you'll be able to call it from the command line like this `dotnet printrefs`

Comment: Oh, and put the batch file in `C:\Program Files\dotnet` and you can use it in any project too

Comment: Neat.  Are there docs on this? What other information can you add?  Can you get the full dependency tree output so you can see what the parent assembly is?

Comment: Added an example for a reverse dependency tree and links to the source code. I don't think there is a good documentation about it though..

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work with .NET Core 2.1+. My thoughts are that the target _ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild_ or ItemGroup _PackageDefinitions_ might have changed names. I'm also not finding any documentation on msbuild targets in use by .NET Core. Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: Ah yeah the resolution was revamped for 2.0, you'd now need to depend on `RunResolvePackageDependencies` AFAIK

Comment: for dotnetcore 3.1+ you need to set 'EmitLegacyAssetsFileItems' to true https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/msbuild

Answer (score 6):

This flashed up today in the `Morning Brew` which might be worth a look:

[Martin Bjorkstrom Dotnet Depends](https://martinbjorkstrom.com/posts/2018-08-06-announcing-dotnet-depends)

Answer (score 5):

You can actually search through dependencies of particular project quite easily in Visual Studio.

Just right click on Dependencies, select "scope to this". And then you can directly search through dependencies.
[image: scope to this]

Answer (score 3):

In the dropdown if Search bar, tick `Search within file contents` and `Search within external items`, and enter the package you want to search to see the dependency tree if this package
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to parse the output from the `dotnet list package` commands directly:

```
dotnet list package --include-transitive
```

It still separates per-csproj, but it keeps them in one "level", and the text is likely easier to parse:

```
dotnet list package --include-transitive

Project 'TestApp' has the following package references
   [net6.0]:
   Top-level Package         Requested             Resolved
   > System.CommandLine      2.0.0-beta1.21308.1   2.0.0-beta1.21308.1

   Transitive Package      Resolved
   > Crayon                2.0.62
   > SomeDep               1.0.0
   > Microsoft.CSharp      4.4.1
   > AnotherDep            1.0.0
   > System.Memory         4.5.4

// ...
```