# Where is full documentation about the csproj format for .net core?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

Is there a full documentation about the csproj format for .net core projects?

I was looking for a way to copy files before building.
After some searching I found a solution, but I can't find the documentation for this. Does it overwrite files? Are there extra options, ...

```
  <Target Name="CopyMyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="../../someFile.js" DestinationFolder="dest/" />
  </Target>
```

I found the additions for .net core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj), but there is nothing about copy.
Does that mean copy is somehting from msbuild?
The target element is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-element-msbuild)
But I don't find anything about copy. Is there a list of possible tasks somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The documentation for the tasks included in MSBuild is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference), with a [page specifically on the copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task).
Sadly, there are many features of the .NET SDK that aren't documented and probably only useful in special scenarios. I find myself looking at the source code of [MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues), the [.NET MSBuild SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) and the [Web Sdk](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk) quite often to see how it is built and what can be done using it - e.g. while researching [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44944566/784387).

Comment: Thanks. Here is the source of the Copy task. I'll take a look at it. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/Copy.cs

Comment: Also see the [MSBuild project file schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2019).  The root of the [MSBuild Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference?view=vs-2019) documentation has links to other relevant documentation.