# Find out which package is referencing a nuget package

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am trying to convert some code to .NET CORE 2.0, but, as I'm nuget restore-ing, I get a lot of NU1701 warnings, saying that some packages were restored using .NET461. Funny thing, is I don't reference these packages. How can I find out which N-level dependency actually references these packages?

And it's ancient versions of the packages as well, so it is definitely some third-party dependency. I would never reference these versions of the packages. Any tips on how I can find where the dependency stems from?

Examples:

```
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 4.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.0.20710' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'WebActivatorEx 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
NU1701: Package 'WebActivatorEx 2.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This may cause compatibility problems.
```

Comment: I posted an msbuild target to help list dependencies at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944172/net-core-dependency-tree/44944566#44944566, maybe the second one of those can help

Comment: Though I'm pretty confident you're directly referencing `Swashbuckle` which doesn't work on .net core (there is a different swashbuckle package for asp.net core)

Comment: You are correct. Swashbuckle was the devil in the details (see my answer below). Switched to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

1. Pipe the nuget restore to a log
2. Select-string `project.assets.json` from the log.
3. Run `Select-String Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` on each of the `project.assets.json`
4. Open the matching ones in an editor. See what dependency depended on `Microsoft.Aspnet.WebApi.Core` (e.g.)

In my case, it was Swashbuckle, which was in a .NET full framework version. Switched to Swachbuckle.AspNetCore, and the dependencies disappeared.

Comment: can u explain point 1

Comment: @Sana E.g. `nuget restore > nuget-restore.log`